# Error in Silverlight app with RadSpreadsheet control

Tags: c#, silverlight, telerik

I am writing a Silverlight app with Telerik Radspreadsheet Control. It runs correctly on Windows 7 and 8 in Firefox, Google Chrome, Opera and IE 9, but some of my clients can not load it on Windows XP in IE 8, and receive this error:

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR     2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Thu, 16 May 2013 13:21:38 UTC


Message: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application     [Parser_CreateInstance_ConstructorInvocation]
Arguments: Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadSpreadsheet
Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient     information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?    linkid=106663&Version=5.1.20125.0&File=System.Windows.dll&Key=Parser_CreateInstance_Constru    ctorInvocation [Line: 47 Position: 40]   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object     component, Uri resourceLocator)
   at ECOBox2012WebPanel.DataPage.InitializeComponent()
   at ECOBox2012WebPanel.DataPage..ctor()
   at ECOBox2012WebPanel.MainPage..ctor()
   at ECOBox2012WebPanel.App.Application_Startup(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
   at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(UInt32 typeIndex, Delegate     handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32     argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName, UInt32 flags)
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://ecobox2012web.say-co.com/default.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed there was an issue that RadSpreadsheet control does not load under Windows XP.

As a member of the team responsible for developing the component, I can confirm that it has already been fixed, so upgrading to the latest official version should solve the problem.